# JQuery link onClick event sends image - how to get the link object instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

I have a dropdown list with image and text on each link item. The data tags are on the link which wraps both text and image. When I click on the text, the jQuery.fn.init gives me the a.dropdown-item as I'd expect, but if the image gets clicked, it gives me the image object instead with the a.dropdown-item as parent.

I thought I'd specified the filter correctly in the function call, but obviously not - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Dropdown item contruct:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/i18n/setlang/" data-nextpage="/ca" data-languagecode="ca">
<img src="/static/ca.png" class="d-inline-block align-middle pb-1" alt="" loading="lazy">
&nbsp;Català
</a>
```

Script start:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#languagelist a').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let target = $(event.target);
            let nextpage = target.data('nextpage');
            let url = target.attr('href');
            let language_code = target.data('languagecode');
            .....
```

I thought specifying 'a' would just give me the link object, but when the image is clicked that's what comes as target (without data tags obviously).

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `target` of the event is always the element at the bottom of the DOM tree which *raised* the event, not the element which *listened* for the event.

To achieve what you require you can either use `event.currentTarget` or the `this` reference within the jQuery event handler function, as both of these refer to the element which the listener is attached to. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#languagelist a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // when clicking on the <img />
    console.log(this); // = <a />
    console.log(event.currentTarget); // = <a />
    console.log(event.target) // = <img />
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="languagelist">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/i18n/setlang/" data-nextpage="/ca" data-languagecode="ca">
    <img src="/static/ca.png" class="d-inline-block align-middle pb-1" alt="" loading="lazy"> &nbsp;Català
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that! Updating the target line to `let target = $(event.currentTarget);` fixed the issue. Looks like I have some reading up to do ;-)

Comment: No problem, glad to help